# Log4j to enable dynamically based on environment

Tags: java, xml, spring, log4j

I have a requirements  to enable the console logs for Dev and SIT instances but not in production. 
Like if(ENV=SIT) do logging otherwise not

And this should  be  dynamic so if requires I can enable the console  logs in production  as well .
It's  means I want to have a variable in log4j.xml .
I gone through  different  filters that that doesn't  deal with environment.

Please  help with sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use springProfile in log4j [Profile-specific Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_profile_specific_configuration)

about spring profile: [Spring profile](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: I can't use spring profile because project is already  implemented and can't  change the configuration with @ profile.    If there any way to do if check before adding console appender.

Comment: You can do something like this :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_profile_specific_configuration.

<springProfile name="!production">
 <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "production" profile is not active -->
</springProfile>

Comment: And just add file appender inside that. Just set active spring profile from command line or as vm arg.

Comment: can u give me an example how to pass variable & check in log..
like if (springProfile name dev=={variable})
then console log

Comment: @don can u pls provide me sample to pass variable & check with spring profile values

Comment: <root level="info">
 <springProfile name="!prod">
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"></appender-ref>
 </springProfile>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingAppender"></appender-ref>
 </root>

Comment: If all the INFO  is logged, then you can use the above code.

Comment: And set -Dspring.profiles.active=<your profile name> in VM arguments.